# How do I clone a Collection<T>?

Tags: c#, powershell, collections, clone

I have an enumeration, `Fruit`, and a class, `FruitCollection`, which derives `Collection<Fruit>`.  I couldn't find a way to clone `FruitCollection` using .NET and I found [this MSDN article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1e279146-7a5b-43ab-ba44-28f19a5a10b8/create-deep-copy-of-collectiont?forum=csharpgeneral) which defined a `DeepClone()` function and used `MemberwiseClone()`.  Now, since this is an enumeration, I don't think I need to "deep" clone it, so I thought `MemberwiseClone()` would be sufficient.  However, when I try it in PowerShell, the cloned object seems to simply be a pointer to the original object and not a clone.  What am I doing wrong?

Is there another way to simply clone a `Collection`?  `FruitCollection` has no other custom members.

C# code:

```
public enum Fruit
{
    Apple = 1,
    Orange = 2
}

public class FruitCollection : Collection<Fruit>
{
    public FruitCollection Clone()
    {
        return Clone(this);
    }

    public static FruitCollection Clone(FruitCollection fruitCollection)
    {
        return (FruitCollection)fruitCollection.MemberwiseClone();
    }

}
```

PowerShell Output:

```
PS> $basket1 = New-Object TestLibrary.FruitCollection
PS> $basket1.Add([TestLibrary.Fruit]::Apple)
PS> $basket2 = $basket1.Clone()
PS> $basket1.Add([TestLibrary.Fruit]::Orange)
PS> $basket2
Apple
Orange
```

Comment: [What is the method MemberwiseClone() doing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289420/what-is-the-method-memberwiseclone-doing)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Are you saying that `Fruit` is a reference type?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's [`object.MemberwiseClone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which is `protected`).

Comment: `object.MemberwiseClone()` doesn't clone the *contents* of a collection. It just copies the fields of the object- in this case, one of the fields will be an array (or other reference collection type), and only the reference is copied.

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewWatson.  So, how do I clone the _contents_ of `FruitCollection`?

Comment: `new FruitCollection(this)` doesn't do the trick?

Comment: @Hossy That's going to depend on what the contents are.  You'll need to have objects that know how to clone themselves.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: No.  I get a compile error: 'TestLibrary.FruitCollection' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: @Servy: The contents are `Fruit` (enumeration).

Comment: Maybe I missed this in the question, but are you trying to clone the collection (new collection, but same items) or are you trying to get a new collection where the items inside the original collection were cloned? EDIT: Nevermind, I see Fruit was an enum.

Comment: `Collection<T>` doesn't have a copy constructor of another `Collection<T>`? or `IEnumerable<T>`? strange.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Maybe I'm missing something obvious.  `new Collection<Fruit>(fruitCollection)` is valid, but returns a `Collection<Fruit>` object and C# does not want to convert `Collection<Fruit>` to `FruitCollection` even though `FruitCollection` is derived from `Collection<Fruit>`.

Comment: @TyCobb: I'm trying to create a new `FruitCollection` that contains the same contents as the original `FruitCollection`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you can use the constructor that already exists on Collection and then in your `Clone`, create a new list for the new Collection to use so adding to basket1 doesn't affect basket2 and so forth.

```
public class FruitCollection : Collection<Fruit>
{
    public FruitCollection(IList<Fruit> source) : base(source)
    {
    }

    public FruitCollection()
    {
    }

    public FruitCollection Clone()
    {
        return Clone(this);
    }

    public static FruitCollection Clone(FruitCollection fruitCollection)
    {
        // ToList() will give a new List. Otherwise Collection will use the same IList we passed.
        return new FruitCollection(fruitCollection.ToList());
    }

}

void Main()
{
    var basket1 = new FruitCollection();
    basket1.Add(Fruit.Apple);
    var basket2 = basket1.Clone();
    basket2.Add(Fruit.Orange);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", basket1.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", basket2.Count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @TyCobb.  I didn't realize `FruitCollection` wouldn't derive the `Collection<T>(IList<T> list)` constructor automatically.

Comment: @Hossy, yea, you have to manually define the constructors you want when inheriting.

Comment: Mmm.. I always fall for this. I'd love auto-ctor-inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are doing a Memberwise clone, which is a shallow copy of the non-static fields of the object. Since your object is a Collection (reference type), it is only copying a reference to the collection.

Try this instead:

```
public class FruitCollection : Collection<Fruit>
{
    public FruitCollection Clone()
    {
        return Clone(this);
    }

    public static FruitCollection Clone(FruitCollection fruitCollection)
    {
        var clonedFruitCollection = new FruitCollection();

        // Deep copy the collection instead of copying the reference with MemberwiseClone()
        foreach (var fruit in fruitCollection)
        {
            clonedFruitCollection.Add(fruit);
        }

        return clonedFruitCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does work, but is there not a better/faster way than iterating through the list?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new FruitCollection and add all elements to it. You can also create a constructor which does this, see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: I tried `return new Collection<Fruit>(fruitCollection);`, but I get an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<TestLibrary.Fruit>' to 'TestLibrary.FruitCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).  `return (FruitCollection)new Collection<Fruit>(fruitCollection);` also fails (at runtime) with the same error.

Comment: Of course: all FruitCollection's are Collection<Fruit>, but not the other way around. You need to create a new FruitCollection. And define your own copy constructor in this class.